# Redefine generic function with different lambda list

Tags: common-lisp, slime, sbcl

I've made a mistake and forgot to specify keyword arguments in `defgeneric` the first time I've compiled it. Now I really don't want to restart SLIME only to redefine this one `defgeneric` to include more arguments. Is there a way to "undefine" it somehow?

Oh, sorry, never mind, after removing all methods defined for that generic, SBCL redefined it, so it's all good now:

```
(remove-method #'some-generic 
  (find-method #'some-generic '() (list of method types)))
```

For posterity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [fmakunbound](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fmakun.htm#fmakunbound).

```
(fmakunbound 'some-generic)
```

Comment: oh, yes, that would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 10):

SLIME has the command <kbd>Ctrl-c Ctrl-u</kbd> to undefine a function. Set the cursor on the function symbol and then type the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to compile one or more methods with the additional arguments and then, after your `Common Lisp` implementation "complains" about the unknown parameters, select the restart which updates the arguments available in the generic function.

Comment: Heh, now I've come to conclusion, I actually want it back w/o the keywords... this appears to be harder :) Just to make sure: my only options at the restart, when I define incompatible methods are to either quit or abort... it doesn't offer to replace anything.